# Loading related objects without multiple database calls

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql

I'm just learning LINQ to SQL and have run into the following obstacle.

**I have a the following 3 tables:**

1. **PC** *(PCGUID, ParentPCGUID, ModelName, RetailerGUID)*
2. **Offer** *(OfferGUID, ParentGUID, Title)*
3. **Retailer** *(RetailerGUID, Name)*

**With the following relationships:**

1. **PC** 1:N **Offer**
2. **Retailer** 1:N **PC**
3. **Retailer** 1:N **Offer**
4. **PC** 1:N **PC** *(self referencing)*

I need to grab records from PC with only 1 record from PC.Offer (with specific where clauses) and only 1 record from PC.Retailer.Offer (with specific where clauses) and, hopefully, with only one hit on the database.

I have the follow query so far (I've tried about a hundred so far), but it hits the db multiple times.

```
    var q = from pc in PCs
        where pc.PCGUID == guid || pc.ParentPCGUID == guid
        select new { 
            PC = pc,
            PCOffers = pc.Offers.FirstOrDefault(),
            RetailOffers = pc.Retailer.Offers.FirstOrDefault()
        };
```

If I bring only one property of the offer table like so:

```
    var q = from pc in PCs
        where pc.PCGUID == guid || pc.ParentPCGUID == guid
        select new { 
            PC = pc,
            PCOffers = pc.Offers.FirstOrDefault().Title,
            RetailOffers = pc.Retailer.Offers.FirstOrDefault().Title
        };
```

It works just fine and only hits the db once, but I need the whole offer object.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try something like this, but I'm not sure it will help.

```
YourDataContext db = new YourDataContext();
db.DeferredLoadingEnabled = false;

DataLoadOptions loadOptions = new DataLoadOptions(); 
loadOptions.LoadWith<PC>(p => p.Offers); 
loadOptions.LoadWith<PC>(p => p.Retailer); 
loadOptions.LoadWith<Retailer>(r => r.Offers); 

db.LoadOptions = loadOptions;
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, but that actually resulted in more calls to the db.  I've tried various data load options to no avail.

Comment: Fair enough. Good luck with it, data load has tended to help me in the past but that's when returning one associated instance, not an anonymous class with multiple instances.